# Привычка курить или привычка к курению?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Надо было написать один текст, но меня вдруг заклинило — а как правильно сказать: "Привычка курить" или "привычка к курению"? Или оба выражения имеют место?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что допустимы оба варианта. В БТС как примеры указаны " привычка к труду", "привычка рано вставать". Получается, что может быть "привычка" к чему? и что делать?